# Embedded Google Maps: weird UI display glitches (with screenshot)

Tags: javascript, css, maps

I have a Google map embedded on a Shopify page. It shows weird UI glitches and I cant find the reason for this behaviour. Please see the screenshots for details.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yypFx.jpg)

It was fine with the previous Shopify theme, maybe something is interfering with the new theme.

This is the HTML for embedding the map:

```html
<div id="gmap"><script async="" defer="" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_api_key&libraries=places&callback=Function.prototype"></script></div>
```

The CSS:

```css
 #gmap {
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;

      }
      #gmap img {
        max-width: none !important;
        max-height: none !important;
      }[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asIML.jpg)
      #gmap label {
        width: auto; display: inline !important;
      }
```

And this is the JavaScript:

```js
function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap'), {
          center: {lat: 51.1, lng: 9.9},
          zoom: 6,
          scrollwheel: true,
          mapTypeControl: true,
          scaleControl: true,
          streetViewControl: false,
          rotateControl: false,
          fullscreenControl: false,
          zoomControl: true,
          controlSize: 32,
        });
```

Any idea what could be the cause of this?